# None of the REGEX I've tried work in an HTML Input Pattern

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to make an HTML input to only be able to receive `float` numbers like: x.123 x,123 x.123456 x,123456

Where x can have one or 2 digits: x or xx.

Basically I would like to know how to make a `pattern` that only accepts those kind of numbers.

Reading around the WEB I found two patterns that should've matched my needs, but they do not work.

`^[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$`
`^(?=.)(\d{1,2}(,\d{3,6})*)?(\.\d+)?$`

These were found, I don't understand how this works.

Googling Regex I found a lot of tools that work for,on or with (I don't have any idea) JavaScript, PHP, RUBY, PCRE.

I don't understand what coding language they use or how. And after digging into it more I found myself even more lost and having more questions.

Is there any reverse tool that actually makes the regex ?

I found this http://buildregex.com/ but I don't know how it works...
This is me trying to make my pattern...

`/(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:)|(?:(?:22\.123))|(?:(?:2\.123))|(?:(?:22\.123))|(?:)|(?:)|(?:))))))/`

EDIT:

This is is the input:

```
<input id="text-input" type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="/^[\d]{1,2}[.,][\d]{3,6}$/"
                                    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a number with 3-6 decimals')"
                                    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"
                                    oninput="setCustomValidity(' ')"
>
```

Comment: `x.y` or `x,y` where x is 1 to 2 digits and y is 3 to 6 digits ?

Comment: Yes, That's correct !

Comment: HTML5 patterns cannot have regex delimiters, `/` are parsed as parts of the regex *pattern*. Also, they are always anchored, they must match the entire string, hence no need using `^` and `$`. Use `pattern="\d{1,2}[.,]\d+"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you ! That's why it wasn't working. Taking `/^[\d]{1,2}[.,][\d]{3,6}$/` from @Cid and removing the delimiters `/` made it work.

Comment: Use `pattern="\d{1,2}[.,]\d{3,6}"` then, no need to wrap `\d`s with brackets, and again, the anchors are added behind the scenes, `^(?:pattern)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pattern="^\d{1,2}[.,]\d{3,6}$"`

`^\d{1,2}` starting with 1 to 2 digit(s)

`[.,]` followed by either a comma, either a dot

`\d{3,6}$` ending by 3 to 6 digits

Comment: The regex itself does what it should do. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/uTgrQa/1).

Comment: It works, but after I removed the `/` delimiters as @WiktorStribiżew said.

Comment: @NicoSchreiner Yes, that's where I was checking too. It was strange. But now it works. Check my other comments.

Answer (score 1):

There're no needs for delimiters and anchors, use:

```
pattern="\d{1,2}[.,]\d{3,6}"
```

Comment: Yes ! That's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d{1,2}[\.]\d{3,6}$ ,
```

`^d{1,2}` means: max 2 digit start with.

`[\.]` means : having **.** in middle.

`d{3,6}` means min 3 and max 6 digit of decimal points at the end.